# Backbone JS: how to parse JSON response with dynamic named objects

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm trying to [parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) the following JSON response to a Backbone.Collection:

```
{
  "16": {
    "_id": "16",
    "lastname": ...,
    ...
  },
  "17": {
    "_id": "17",
    "lastname": ...,
    ...
  },
    ...
  },
  "39": {
    "_id": "39"
    "lastname": ...,
    ...
  }
}
```

How could one parse the set of name/value pairs ("_id", "lastname", ...)?

Comment: Please provide an example of the output you are looking for.

Comment: this could be parsed to the collection:
[{
    "_id": "17",
    "lastname": ...,
    ...
  },
  {
    "_id": "18",
    "lastname": ...,
    ...
  }, ...
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to return an array in order to parse it to a collection.

so in your parse function:

```
parse: function (response) {
  return _.map(response, function(obj) {
    return obj;
  });
}
```

make sure in your model, you have defined the correct idAttribute since you are using non-standard id name:

```
var YourModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: "_id"
});
```